# In Vue3 how to transfer async data to the child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am trying to transfer async data from a parent file to a child component. It is currently giving error in the child component as the parent loads the data in the onMounted event. What is the correct way to do this?

Parent:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import TestForm from '../components/TestForm.vue';

const testMe = ref();
// testMe.value = {
//   id: 1,
//   startDateTime: '2023-06-26T09:43:32.203Z',
// };

onMounted(() => {
  const newObject2 = fetchData();
  console.log('onMounted testing newObject2', newObject2);
  testMe.value = newObject2;
});

async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/testMes');
  const data = await res.json();
  const newObject = data[0];
  console.log('testing the async function data from json:', newObject);
  return newObject;
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <TestForm :testProps="testMe" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Child: TestForm.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['testProps']);

const startDateTime = ref('');

// eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-setup-props-destructure
startDateTime.value = props.testProps.startDateTime;
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ startDateTime }}
  </div>
</template>
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'startDateTime')

which I think I understand why, but what is the right way to transfer these values to the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get data

Since `fetchData()` is an asynchronous function and we don't know when it will finish, you need to add the instruction to wait for the `newObject2` variable to receive the result of the `fetchData()` function. The instruction you should use is `await`.

```js
onMounted(async () => {
  testMe.value = await fetchData(); // here
});
```

#### Transfer to child component (prop)

```js
startDateTime.value = props.testProps.startDateTime;
```

This line is executed during component initialization and only assigns the value of `testProps.startDateTime` to the `startDateTime` reference once. This means that `startDateTime` will not be automatically updated when `testMe` changes in the parent component.

To make `testProps` update with changes to the `testMe` variable, the child component needs to watch `testProps` and react to its changes. For this purpose, the `onUpdated` lifecycle hook should be used in the child component.

```js
const props = defineProps(['testProps']);

const startDateTime = ref('');

onUpdated(() => {
  startDateTime.value = props.testProps.startDateTime;
});
```

Comment: with onUpdated it worked. I could not make the alternative solution work though. Do you have any references for that?

Comment: I deleted the second solution. I wanted to quickly write a shorter solution... I rushed it. I will check what other options there are besides this, and as soon as I have the opportunity, I will update my answer. I'm glad that the current solution managed to achieve its goal!